# Is windows docker images the same with windows container images?

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-server-2016

I was following [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_powershell) to learn about Windows Container in Windows Server TP4. Since the article came with both 'Powershell way' and ['docker way'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_docker), then I thought that both ways are interchangeable. I thought that container and container image created from powershell can be managed from docker and vise versa.

Then after I finished and created everything in powershell, I run `docker images` and `docker ps`, and my containers / images are not there?!

Am I missing something or really they are both different things?

Answer (score 6):

Currently in TP4 of Windows Server 2016 there are two methods of running and managing containers. Docker and PowerShell.

They are not interchangeable at this time.

So get-containerimage will only fetch PowerShell created Images and 
docker images will only fetch Docker created images

I do not know if it is the plan to make them completely interchangeable for the RTM version.

Yours

Ed

Answer (score 1):

The situation is the same in TP5 - the container images are the same for each type of container but the method of control is limited to the method used to create the container from the image.